# Need advice about function pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have two functions with following signatures:

```
int f1(void* data);
```

and

```
int f2(const void* data);
```

Then I do this:

```
int (*f) (void*) = f2;
```

E.g. I need one pointer type to refer to both functions. However, I get a warning because of removing that const modifier. Is there any way around that? (I can't change f1 and f2 signatures)

Let me explain why I need this. The thing is I was writing wrappers for read() and write() system calls and I noticed that both of them were identical except for call to read() or write(). So I decided to make one wrapper function and pass the needed function using a pointer. So it's all just to get rid of copy-paste. And now I'm not sure if it was a good idea at all.

Comment: You might be able to make an `int f3(void* data)` that just hands off to f2. Would that work for you?

Comment: @JohnColeman: This is bad advice without further information to a beginner.

Comment: Using the wrapper is nonsense. Identical/similar signature does not mean identical semantics (as the `const` clearly implies). Why would one use either function dynamically for the same argument? You just obfuscate your code and eventually run into trouble debugging or extending. Note: what is the difference writing `fread` or `myreadfunction`?

Comment: @Olaf Thank you, I got your point

Comment: @JohnColeman: 1) This will be read by others, too. 2) I disagree, otherwise OP would know about the implications 3) Just see what he seems to want to accomplish. 4) This is a (bad) solution looking for a problem or an XY-problem.

Comment: My original comment was before OP added that business about wrapping `read()` and `write()`. I assumed that they had a good reason for doing what they wanted to do. You are correct that in this case it makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

Is an union working ?

```
union generic_void
{
    void       *data;
    void const *const_data;
} generic_void_t;

int (*f) (generic_void_t) = f1;
int (*f) (generic_void_t) = f2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`f1` anf `f2` have different signatures and creating a pointer capable of taking either value is prone to undefined behavior.

> I need one pointer type to refer to both functions. ...  Is there any way around that?

Do not include a signature in the function pointers arguments.

```
int f1(void* data);
int f2(const void* data);

int fooy(void) {
  int (*fp1)() = f1;
  int (*fp2)() = f2;
  void* data1;
  const void* data2;
  return (*fp1)(data1) + (*fp2)(data2);
}
```

This defeats type checking in `(*fp1)(data1) + (*fp2)(data2)` as code could call `(*fp1)(data2)` or `(*fp2)(1,2,3)`. Code is on the precipice.